# How to map three collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have three collection in monogdb.how to map three collection.I tried it but its not working can give some code or examples.

**Group_promotion.collection**

```
[
{
  "id":1,
   group_name:"Latest",
   products_id:[10,20]
}]
```

**product.collection**

```
[
{
  "id":10,
   product_name:"bourbon",
   category_id:20
},{
  "id":20,
   product_name:"cream",
   category_id:20
}]
```

**Category.collection**

```
[
{
  "id":20,
   name:"beat"
}]
```

**Excepted Ouput**

```
[
{
  "id":1,
   group_name:"Latest",
   products_id:[
{
  "id":10,
   product_name:"bourbon",
   name:"beat"
},{
  "id":20,
   product_name:"cream",
   name:"beat"
}]
}]
```

Comment: @ Fanpark This Scenario how to handlie it .can give some example code .I tried it but its not working.

Comment: Post the code you've tried, not just the collections.